# CSS Horizontal Menu: display: inline AND block? Make link cover whole LI?

Tags: css, menu, inline

Normally, to make the link fill out the whole `li`, I use `display: block;`. But with a horizontal menu, I need to set it to display:inline; so it goes in one line. I've tried `display:inline-block;` but that doesn't help. I've seen horizontal menus that accomplish this, but I can't find out how from their source.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add a width to the li?

Comment: do you have an example of the code you're using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply `height` and `width` to the parent `li` elements, and then:

```
a {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RjNnx/1/).

Comment: display: inline-block will not work on ie7 and ie6, so this is not a good solution.

Comment: @Fatih: to quote [PPK](http://www.quirksmode.org/): ["IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural `display: inline`."](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) And the `a` element is, 'naturally' `display: inline`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

li a {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

See: http://pastehtml.com/view/1cdzwnz.html

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of using `float` s. Think I prefer `inline` or `inline-block`, but worth remembering.

Comment: Ok, any particular reason? `display: inline` wont allow you to apply vertical padding/margins.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
ul.menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
ul.menu>li>a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that your setup:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your link will not fill out the `<li>`, but the `<li>` will still be a block element. Make the `<li>` `display: inline`:

```
ul#nav li {display: inline;}
```

Or float the li and give it a width:

```
ul#nav {overflow: hidden;}
ul#nav li {float: left; width: 50%;}
```